# Limiting the number of outputs in a code block, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, variables, limit, codeblocks

I have this piece of code in my Posts index view:

```
<% @exercises.each do |exercise| %>
    <% if exercise.post_id == post.id %>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th style="color:white;"><%= exercise.name %></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Each post has potentially 5+ exercises associated with it, but I want to only display 5 for each post on the index page.  I can't figure out how to limit the number for each post.  I've tried the limit function at the beginning of the block '@exercises.limit(5).each' but that only does the first 5 exercises that exist.  The instance variable in the controller looks like:

```
@exercises = Exercise.all
```

UPDATE:
Here are my models:

```
class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :extype  
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    searchkick
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :comments
    has_many :exercises

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises
end
```

There isn't any other relevant code in my view, and not much in my controller:

```
def index

    @exercises = Exercise.all


    if params[:category].blank?
        @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @posts = Post.where(:category_id => @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
end
```

Comment: You don't want .all against Exercises.  You want just the exercises for the post, usually something like @post.exercises.limit(5).  You only have a snippet of code, so not quite sure that I'm referencing correctly what you've got from the controller or overall view, but that's the gist of what you want.

Comment: I've tried something like that, but I get undefined method 'exercises', and I think its because posts aren't associated with an exercise_id.

Comment: You need to post more code.   At least the action from the controller and a more complete portion of the view.  Then I can possibly offer a more targeted answer.  Does exercise have a post_id?

Comment: Please post your  `exercise` and `post` model.

Comment: @ChrisWalters I have posted an answer that would solve your problem. Please try it out and let me know if you have any other question.

Comment: I've tried out your solution K M, but I need to define @post variable for my index view and I'm stuck.  I'll try and call find_post '@post = Post.find(params[:id])' but I get an error that says it can't find a post without an id, which I think makes sense in the index view but I don't know how to get through it

Comment: @rdnewman, yes exercise has post_id

Comment: @ChrisWalters You can't do that in `index` that way. 
The solution I showed you will work for your `show` action because you already have access to a particular post (`@post`) in your show action. Don't you want that?

Usually, in the index page of your Post, you would want to show all of your `posts`. Then, if someone goes to view a `post` and goes to the show page, then you would want to show the post's corresponding exercises (5 in your case). Please clarify your requirement a bit.

Comment: @ChrisWalters Or, if you really want to do it in your `index`, then you can directly call: `Exercise.where(post_id: post.id).limit(5)` in your view to get the exercises for a particular post. I think that would work. Try that and let me know.

Comment: Sure, sorry about that KM, I have my show page all set up and it shows all of the exercises for the specifc post.  In my index I have all of the posts laid out and I want to show a preview of the first 5 exercises per post before you click on it t go to the show page, does that make sense?/is it doable?

Comment: Sure it's doable. It depends based on your business requirement.
But, the question is, how you would want to do this. If you want to show 5 exercises for a post in Post's index view, how you would want to show that? in tabular form? or something else? etc.

Comment: yes, tabular form makes the most sense to me. I've tried calling Exercise.where(post_id: post.id).limit(5) directly in the index, but I'm not sure if I'm setting it up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** Based on assumption that, `Post` `has_many` `exercises` and `Exercise` `belongs_to` `post`. ***

Add the following method in your `Exercise` Model's class:

```
   def self.exercises_to_display_for_post(post)
      Exercise.where(post_id: post.id).limit(5)
   end
```

This method will retrieve only 5 `exercises` for a particular `post`.

Then, in your `PostsController`:

```
@exersises_to_display_for_post = Exercise.exercises_to_display_for_post(@post)
```

Then, you can use `@exersises_to_display_for_post` instance variable in your `view` where you have exactly 5 `exercises` corresponding to that  `@post`!

In your view, you have access to `@post` instance variable and it's corresponding 5 `exercises` in the `@exersises_to_display_for_post` instance variable. Now, you just need to loop through them and show!

Comment: Okay, I've figured it out.  You're comment about directly calling `Exercise.where(post_id: post.id).limit(5)` in the view helped. Looping through with  `<% Exercise.where(post_id: post.id).limit(5).each do |exercise| %>` did the trick.  Thank you